# Force Rails cookie to send for any kind of connection (secure/nonsecure)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

I'm setting a cookie in the browser like so:

```
def set_browser_cookie
  cookies.permanent[:ignore_stats_cookie] = {
    :value => STAT_COOKIE,
    :domain => :all,
    :secure => false,
    :httponly => false
  }
  redirect_to settings_path
end
```

When I look at the cookie in Chrome in DEVELOPMENT, the cookie allows for any kind of connection.

[image: localhost]

When I look at the cookie in Chrome in PRODUCTION, the cookie is only allowing secure connections (the app itself is https).

[image: production]

I'm setting the cookie to `:secure => false,` so why is the cookie being set for secure connections only in production?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, and was able to reproduce on my development machine using the `tunnels` gem as a proxy, and setting `force_ssl = true` in 'development' environment.

I've debugged Rack and ActionPack, and found that the header is being sent without `; secure` at the end, but it is modified after that.

My next step would be to use Wireshark to capture the SSL session and decrypt it, but I've run out of time.

I tested using a PHP app hosted behind nginx, and while using HTTPS, the server was able to send cookies that did not include the `secure` flag. So this issue is definitely specific to the stack that we're using with Rails, not a browser issue.